# CSS - Wave borders on landing page image, NOT just a wave

Tags: html, css

I have an SVG for my wave from getwaves.io.

Now I have a wave with this code:

```
.wave {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```
<div class="topbanner">
      <h1 align="center">I Help Counsellors<br><span class="get-clients">Get Clients</span></h1>
        
      <div class="row">
            
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="result" align="center"></div>

        <svg class="wave" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
          <path fill="#5000ca" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,256L48,229.3C96,203,192,149,288,154.7C384,160,480,224,576,218.7C672,213,768,139,864,128C960,117,1056,171,1152,197.3C1248,224,1344,224,1392,224L1440,224L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"></path>
        </svg>
      </div> 

    </div> <!-- End topbanner -->
```

But it's a separate wave overlapping my landing page image I want the borders of my landing page image to be waves like this:

https://patcs.com/

Comment: If i understanded correrctly you want your content in a div with border-wave?
To do so a a full-width div under the wave of the same color and another wave reversed under that.
Then add contents in the div

Comment: Could you please show us the actual problem and the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your svg as a background image to the section and adjust its placement and size using css. Like here https://codepen.io/venkateshpataballa/pen/MzXZqz but without animation.

```css
body
{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.ocean {
    background: #3b21ff;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.wave {
    background: url(https://venkat369.github.io/development/wave.svg) repeat-x; 
    position: absolute;
    top: -198px;
    width: 6400px;
    height: 198px;
    animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.wave:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: -175px;
    animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) -.125s infinite, swell 7s ease -1.25s infinite;
    opacity: 1;
}
@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1600px;
  }
}
@keyframes swell {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-25px,0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0,5px,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fliud">
 
<div class="ocean">
                <div class="wave"></div>
                <div class="wave"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```